# encryption algorithmn to get limited cipher text for any sort of any inputs

Tags: java, encryption

Is that any encryption algorithmn which gives limited cipher characters for any sort of input values in java

Comment: Do you mean something like base64?

Comment: Yes mean something like AES and MD5

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm.  Are you looking for hashing or encrypting?

Comment: Yes object.hashcode will give interger value i am looking for algorithmn like TripleDEST,AES

Comment: Please put more effort in creating a clear and concise question.

Comment: I am not sure what is requested here. Would running base64 on the encrypted data be an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a fixed length hash value of your encrypted text. Encrypt the text with whatever algorithm you want and then hash it with MD5 or any other hashing algorithm. The hash would be practically unique for the input.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to decrypt again then you can use hash codes.

```
object.hashCode()
```

Comment: Yes object.hashcode will give interger value i am looking for algorithmn like TripleDEST,AES